# How to search through Object value department.name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Employee {
    "Name": "Shahid Khawja",
    "email": "Shaid@gmail.com",
    "department": {
        "name": "software developer",
        "id": "60587c8c85657a42ace1d9da"
    }
    "id": "60587c8c85657a42ace1d7ef"
  }
```

```
Department {
    "name": "software developer",
    "id": "60587c8c85657a42ace1d9da"
}
```

I have two collection and I want to search with the help of populate how to search department.name pass through query string

Comment: Edited for readability. Could you please post a code snippet of what you've tried so far. Your question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your query string in regex of populate.

5.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    email: String,
    department: {ref: 'department', type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});

let DepartmentSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});


run().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

    const EmployeeModel = mongoose.model('employee', EmployeeSchema);
    const DepartmentModel = mongoose.model('department', DepartmentSchema);
    const departmentObj = new DepartmentModel({name: "software developer"});
    const {_id} = await departmentObj.save();
    const employeeObj = new EmployeeModel({email: 'xyz@gmail.com', Name: "alexa", department: _id});
    const result = await (await employeeObj.save()).populate({path: 'department', match: {
       name: {$regex: 'soft'}
   }}).execPopulate()
   console.log(result)
}
```